# Parents and siblings in query in XCTest (UI testing)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xctest

In other languages is possible to make such query:

```
class:B text:"text_I_looking_for" sibling class:C
```

or

```
class:B text:"text_I_looking_for" parent class:A child class:C
```

How to perform such query in XCTest? I need find element to
1. Check if it's present
2. Click it.

PS I know XCTest has simply syntax, but in some cases it's not enough solution. Maybe it's possible to use NSPredicate syntax?

Comment: What? It's really not clear what you're asking. XCTest is for automating hand written tests, not running queries. Can you add an example of what you're trying to do in some other programming language?

Comment: Sounds like they are talking about the new GUI testing, which does use queries to get at UI elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I find out Xcode 7.3 is using this mechanism:

```
XCUIApplication().otherElements.containingType(.Image, identifier:"circle").staticTexts["3"]
```

This query will return staticText object with "3" as value.
This object has 'otherElement' as a parent and 'Image' with id 'circle' as sibling.

Answer (score 0):

.containingType was obsoleted in Swift 3. You can use .containing instead (I'm on Xcode 13):

```
XCUIApplication().otherElements.containing(.image, identifier: "circle").staticTexts["3"]
```